# Set range of numbers for IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set a specific range of numbers for an IN clause in SQL Server for example, if the values of 1 - 100 are in column A, then do this...etc. My example below of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN (values of 1 to 100) IN (columnA) THEN columnB
     ELSE ...
     END AS [column]
FROM table
```

Is this possible what I am trying to do within SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the syntax would be:

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN columnA BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN columnB
     ELSE ...
     END AS [column]
FROM table
```

See the documentation on CASE statements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).